# How to update Song name shoutcast in iOS?

Tags: ios, streaming, shoutcast

I'm trying to create a iphone app for a station on Shoutcast. I'm using streamingkit(https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit) to stream the music but I'm not sure How do i get the current song and Artist name. Has anyone ever done this before or knows How to exactly get the song name and artist?

Edit: Trying https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFSoundManager now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should registester a KVO for your player like this

```
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Then use it like this to update the UI:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"timedMetadata"])
    {
        AVPlayerItem* playerItem = object;

        for (AVMetadataItem* metadata in playerItem.timedMetadata)
        {
            //Assign metadata to nsstring info
            NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", metadata.stringValue];
            MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster.png"]];

            NSMutableDictionary *nowPlayingInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [nowPlayingInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Now playing - %@", info] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
            [nowPlayingInfo setObject:info forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            [nowPlayingInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

            [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo;

            NSLog(@"Now Playing: %@", info);

            NSArray *metadata = [info componentsSeparatedByString: @"- "];

            self.artist.text = [metadata objectAtIndex:0];
            self.song.text = [metadata objectAtIndex:1];

        }
    }
}
```

Note: playerItem is an instance of AVPlayerItem.

Comment: Thanks @Vincent, let me try this

Comment: Are you registering the observer?

Comment: yes I'm _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:item.URL];                                           
                   [_player play];                                                         
                                    [_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

Comment: and i'm trying with AFSoundManager

Comment: The observer is for the AVPlayerItem is the one that is changing

Comment: this is what I tried now http://i.imgur.com/43k7g6w.png but its crashing. line no. 44 https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFSoundManager/blob/master/Classes/AFSoundPlayback.m it doesn't crash if I remove the observer

Comment: its working :) btw what is self.station here? Label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76090/discussion-between-vincent-and-ankit).

Comment: btw "poster.png" is not really important here right?

Comment: one more thing, your code doesn't pause/play the music on lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

Why not getting current song and artist name from the shoutcast server? The following pages allow you to retrieve:

```
Current song:     http://yourstream:port/currentsong?sid=#
Last 20 songs:    http://yourstream:port/played.html?sid#
```

More can be found on: [Shoutcast Public pages](http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_DNAS_Server_2#Public_Pages)